# Z-standardization makes PC1 and PC2 exactly the same in this PCA analysis: Why?

Tags: r, pca, psych, standardized

I am trying to perform a PCA analysis using the psych package in R.

I got two variables that I want to combine into one component displaying standard of living:

- slvpen: Standard of living of pensioners: 0 = Extremely bad, 10 = Extremely good.
- slvuemp: Standard of living of unemployed: 0 = Extremely bad, 10 = Extremely good.

**slvpens:**

`Min.   1st Qu. Median    Mean  3rd Qu.    Max.    Standard Deviation 
 0.000   3.000   5.000   4.587   6.000   10.000               2.28857`

**slvuemp:**

`Min.   1st Qu.  Median   Mean  3rd Qu.    Max.    Standard Deviation 
 0.000   3.000   4.000   4.095   5.000   10.000              2.099822`

Using the phych-package, I perfom the analysis:

```
(slv_pca <- ESS %>% prcomp(
  formula = ~ slvpens + slvuemp, # Selecting variables
  data = ., na.action = na.exclude)) # Exclude NAs
```

With the following results:

```
Standard deviations (1, .., p=2):
[1] 2.651352 1.611470

Rotation (n x k) = (2 x 2):
               PC1        PC2
slvpens -0.7699869  0.6380597
slvuemp -0.6380597 -0.7699869
```

Everything is good. However, if I z-standardize the variables:

```
(slv_pca <- ESS %>% prcomp(
  formula = ~ slvpens + slvuemp, # Selecting variables
  data = ., na.action = na.exclude, # Exclude NAs
  center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)) # Z-standardize
```

The picture changes and both PC1 and PC2 is equal. Also, my two components contribute exactly the same?

```
Standard deviations (1, .., p=2):
[1] 1.2058739 0.7388289

Rotation (n x k) = (2 x 2):
               PC1        PC2
slvpens -0.7071068  0.7071068
slvuemp -0.7071068 -0.7071068
```

What is going on here?

Comment: You should try to do just a `scale` and not use the `center` option. (Is just a trial!! :) )
In this way you will scale just the data.
In alternative you will scale the data out of the function.

Comment: @SlowLearning, Thanks for the suggestion! I tried removing the `center` option but no difference at all!

Comment: The problem should be the correlation between the two series. 
I think that the correlation will be almost 1.
At this stage, I suggest you to migrate the question to Cross Validated.

Comment: Your data is already scaled, since it is ordinal. Remember the purpose of scale is to ensure they have the same range and it's already the case for your data, so why scale?

Comment: Also for ordinal data, you can also consider other methods of analysis https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data

Comment: @StupidWolf, why do you characterize it as ordinal and not interval?

Comment: sounds like ordinal to me? https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-numerical-variables/ .. scale 1 to 10 ? good to bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of scaling / centering before PCA is to ensure you give your variables equal weight, and center your PC scores, see more [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385775/normalizing-vs-scaling-before-pca). Right now you have two variables that are already on the same scale.

You don't need to scale, see my example below:

```
# here i convert the iris columns into 1:10 ranks
scale_iris  =apply(iris[,1:4],2,function(i)as.numeric(cut(i,10,labels=1:10)))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(prcomp(iris[,1:4],scale=TRUE,center=TRUE)$x[,1:2],
col=factor(iris$Species),main="Actual iris PCA")
plot(prcomp(scale_iris,center=TRUE)$x[,1:2],
col=factor(iris$Species),main="Scale iris PCA")
```

[image]

If there is information in the ordinal variables, and they are on the same scale, it will be captured by the PCA.

And also of note, by default `prcomp()` centers the data (as it should) and does not scale unless specified.

Comment: Thanks. It makes perfectly sense - and works perfectly. However, centering (true/false) still makes a huge difference? According to your link, it is recommended to center the data. But why?

Comment: Ok sorry I checked the code for prcomp again, it by default centers the data. So yes, you are right, you should center the data. This is so that you have a PC score that passes through the origin.. Otherwise the scores will be weird, and you have trouble using them

Comment: you can check this post, the plot https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22329/how-does-centering-the-data-get-rid-of-the-intercept-in-regression-and-pca, in general i think of it as like regression. if you don't center, you might have some issues with using the scores